# Why is jet mass super-correlated with jet pt?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

I came across this statement recently in some event "Jet mass is correleted with jet pt". The reason was somewhat related to QCD; that for jets, the mass comes from the actual massive particles unlike quarks and thus they are correlated. But could someone please explain me this in some more detail?
Thank you very much!

Comment: these slides have a nice summary of jets and their successful simulation. http://web.mit.edu/panic11/talks/tuesday/PARALLEL-3K/2-1400/rappoccio/270-0-rappoccio_panic2011.pdf . You have to give a link to your statement. In general, because the p_t plane is invariant to the beam energy lorentz boost, it is a snapshot of the distributions in the center of mass. Hi p_t is a possible  signal for a deep inelastic interaction or a large mass decay. I cannot figure out the statement you quote.

Comment: @annav  Sure! The slides provide quite good summary. Probably, I'll see if I can get some more information on that! Anyways, thanks a lot!